# Formatted DateTime e.g. "Since last year"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to print the DateTime of the posts but in format like this (Since one hour, Since yesterday, or Since last year), I succeeded to do it using the following code.
But, Is there a better way to do it like this code??
Note: there is a property called Date in this code.

```
public string GetFormattedDate()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var years = now.Year - Date.Year;

    // Calculating leap year
    if (Date.Date > now.AddYears(-years)) years--;

    if (years > 0)
    {
        return "Since " + ((years > 1) ? $"{years} years" : "last year");
    }

    var months = now.Month - Date.Month;

    if (months > 0)
    {
        return "Since " + ((months > 1) ? $"{months} months" : "last month");
    }

    var days = now.Day - Date.Day;

    if (days > 0)
    {
        return "Since " + ((days > 1) ? $"{days} days" : "yesterday");
    }

    var hours = now.Hour - Date.Hour;

    if (hours > 0)
    {
        return "Since " + ((hours > 1) ? $"{hours} hours" : "one hour");
    }

    var minutes = Math.Abs(now.Minute - Date.Minute);

    if (minutes > 0)
    {
        return "Since " + ((minutes > 1) ? $"{minutes} minutes" : "one minute");
    }

    return "Now";
}
```

Comment: Depending on whether the rest of the functionality is worth the size of the project, [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-datetime) has this feature built in.

Comment: That's great but It's too large like you said and not worth it. So, I used their Algorithms instead. Really helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another Algorithm which is way better than mine.
Thanks to all the contributors in [Humanizr](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) and of course to [Tieson T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534109/tieson-t)

```
public static class DateTimeHumanize
{
    public static string Humanize(this DateTime input, DateTime comparisonBase)
    {
        var ts = new TimeSpan(Math.Abs(comparisonBase.Ticks - input.Ticks));

        int seconds = ts.Seconds, minutes = ts.Minutes, hours = ts.Hours, days = ts.Days;
        int years = 0, months = 0;

        // start approximate from smaller units towards bigger ones
        if (ts.Milliseconds >= 999)
        {
            seconds += 1;
        }

        if (seconds >= 59)
        {
            minutes += 1;
        }

        if (minutes >= 59)
        {
            hours += 1;
        }

        if (hours >= 23)
        {
            days += 1;
        }

        // month calculation 
        if (days >= 30 & days <= 31)
        {
            months = 1;
        }

        if (days > 31 && days < 365)
        {
            var factor = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)days / 30));
            var maxMonths = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)days / 30));
            months = (days >= 30 * factor) ? maxMonths : maxMonths - 1;
        }

        // year calculation
        if (days >= 365 && days <= 366)
        {
            years = 1;
        }

        if (days > 365)
        {
            var factor = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)days / 365));
            var maxMonths = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)days / 365));
            years = (days >= 365 * factor) ? maxMonths : maxMonths - 1;
        }

        if (years > 0)
        {
            return "Since " + ((years > 1) ? $"{years} years" : "last year");
        }

        if (months > 0)
        {
            return "Since " + ((months > 1) ? $"{months} months" : "last month");
        }

        if (days > 0)
        {
            return "Since " + ((days > 1) ? $"{days} days" : "yesterday");
        }

        if (hours > 0)
        {
            return "Since " + ((hours > 1) ? $"{hours} hours" : "one hour");
        }

        if (minutes > 0)
        {
            return "Since " + ((minutes > 1) ? $"{minutes} minutes" : "one minute");
        }

        return "Now";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string RelativeDate(DateTime theDate)
{
    Dictionary<long, string> thresholds = new Dictionary<long, string>();
    int minute = 60;
    int hour = 60 * minute;
    int day = 24 * hour;
    thresholds.Add(60, "{0} seconds ago");
    thresholds.Add(minute * 2, "a minute ago");
    thresholds.Add(45 * minute, "{0} minutes ago");
    thresholds.Add(120 * minute, "an hour ago");
    thresholds.Add(day, "{0} hours ago");
    thresholds.Add(day * 2, "yesterday");
    thresholds.Add(day * 30, "{0} days ago");
    thresholds.Add(day * 365, "{0} months ago");
    thresholds.Add(long.MaxValue, "{0} years ago");
    long since = (DateTime.Now.Ticks - theDate.Ticks) / 10000000;
    foreach (long threshold in thresholds.Keys) 
    {
        if (since < threshold) 
        {
            TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan((DateTime.Now.Ticks - theDate.Ticks));
            return string.Format(thresholds[threshold], (t.Days > 365 ? t.Days / 365 : (t.Days > 0 ? t.Days : (t.Hours > 0 ? t.Hours : (t.Minutes > 0 ? t.Minutes : (t.Seconds > 0 ? t.Seconds : 0))))).ToString());
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```